# How to create RAW or Virtual Hard Disk (VHD), or ESX Virtual Machine Disk (VMDK) disk in Linux?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Amazon EC2 allows import of disk volumes to EBS as documented here. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/importing-your-volumes-into-amazon-ebs.html

Trouble is I can find no explanation anywhere for how to create an EXT2 or EXT4 formatted disk in RAW, VHD or VMDK which can then be imported. Can someone point me in the right direction of how to do this?

thanks

Comment: With your local hypervisor?

Answer (score 2):

A raw disk image with no headers and no dynamic allocation of space is supported natively by Linux. Creating it is quite simple:

```
head -c1M /dev/zero >disk-image-file
mkfs.ext4 disk-image-file
mount -o loop disk-image-file /path/to/mount/point
```

Caveats: A file created this way will be as large as the virtual drive regardless of how much space is actually used within the virtual file system. A virtual drive created this way will not be partitioned.

If those caveats are a problem for you, then you may be better off to create the image file using the same virtualization software which you want to host it on afterwards.